# Can infinite polynomials be expressed as a product of its linear factors?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, factorization, analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory

**Background**:
In the 1700s, Euler solved the Basel Problem, which was to solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ in closed-form.  Euler showed that it was equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by first expressing $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in Taylor series form, and then writing it as the normalized product of the linear factors given by its roots.

$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = (1 - \frac{x}{\pi})(1 - \frac{x}{-\pi})(1 - \frac{x}{2\pi})(1 - \frac{x}{-2\pi})...$

When multiplied out and the x^2 terms are collected, they come out to $-\frac{1}{\pi^2}(\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{n^2})$, which corresponds to x^2's coefficient of -1/6 in the Taylor Series expansion.  Thus, the infinite sum comes out to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

**My question**
I have a function with an infinite number of complex zeroes, is continuous and differentiable everywhere, and has no infinities, complex or otherwise, for finite input (I believe this is called a holomorphic function, but I have yet to take a complex analysis class, so I'm not 100% sure).  For reference, my function is $(x-1)\zeta(x)$.  At x=1, this function is equal to 1, according to Mathematica.

**Please note**
At x = 0, $(x-1)\zeta(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

If z is a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(x)$, so is 1-z

The trivial zeroes of $\zeta(x)$ are the negative even numbers

In the same fashion that Euler described sin(x)/x as the normalized product of its linear factors, can this function also be expressed as the normalized product of its linear factors?  Namely, if $z_k$ is the kth non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function with "positive" imaginary component, then is this true:

$(x-1)\zeta(x) = (1/2)\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-\frac{x}{z_n})(1-\frac{x}{1-z_n})(1+\frac{x}{2n})$

If not, why not?

**Additional question**
In general, the only two classes of functions I can think of without any complex zeroes are non-zero constants and exponentials.  So, can all functions be expressed as a product of a constant, an exponential, and its normalized linear factors?

If I need to make anything clearer, please let me know.  I'm hastily posting this from a school computer and I might not be as clear as I would like.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: Please read FAQ. This site is for research level questions.
Which means, in particular, that BEFORE you ask a question 
on complex analysis here, you are supposed to take at least an undergraduate course on it.

Comment: The summary may be: finish your complex analysis class, it should include certain product representations.

Comment: @Gerald: which complex analysis classes? I certainly didn't see Weierstrass factorization in my undergraduate complex analysis class.

Comment: @Gabriel: try various textbooks on complex analysis: e.g. Chapter VII, Section 5 of J. B. Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello Gabriel,

I think you should indeed have a look at the theory of (entire) holomorphic/meromorphic functions, since $x\mapsto (x-1)\zeta(x)$ belongs to that class. You more particularly wish to learn about Hadamard or Weierstrass factorization theorems [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function), as pointed out in the comment by Andres. There you should reasonnably find the answers to your questions.

Comment: For the specific case of $(s-1)\zeta(s)$, the Hadamard product representation is given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Hadamard_product (you can combine it with a representation for $\Gamma(1+s/2)=(s/2)\Gamma(s/2)$ using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions).

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is indeed what I was looking for, but I didn't know what it was called.  I'll take a look at the articles and try and decipher it.  From what it looks like, I had the general idea down, but I was missing the pi exponential and some Gamma function stuff.